# Issue with Webpack Sass-Loader /sass-loader/dist/cjs.js Deprecation Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated

Tags: webpack, deprecated, sass-loader

Anyone experiencing this warning issue with webpack sassloader? Please open the attached image
[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpeTT.jpg)
This is my package.json, with webpack, sass, sass loader

```
{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack serve --open"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.11",
    "@babel/node": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.14",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js followed the recommendation from the webpack documentation.

```
const path = require("path");
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (env) => {
  return {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
      index: "./src/js/index.js",
    },
    output: {
      filename: "[name].bundle.js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      clean: true,
    },
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    devServer: {
      static: "./dist",
      port: 8080,
      hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
      }),
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
            "style-loader",
            // Translates CSS into CommonJS
            "css-loader",
            // Compiles Sass to CSS
            {
              loader: "sass-loader",
              options: {
                // Prefer `dart-sass`
                implementation: require("sass"),
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
          type: "asset/resource",
        },
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [{loader: "babel-loader"}],
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".*", ".js", ".jsx"],
    }
  };
};
```

Tried to use different version of sass loader but didn't work. Not sure what is going wring.